# Sorting Custom ListView with Image and Text items

Tags: android, android-listview

I have custom `ListView` in my android application. It consists images and title and content like subtitle and price. Here I want to sort my `ListView` in price basis. Any one can help me? How to sort the `ListView`. For example pls refer the following link if possible to sort the list in degree basis...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507651/Customized-Android-ListView-with-Image-and-Text

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort the data structure before setting in the listview.  it is only the possible way i think

Answer (score 1):

First sort your data like this

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<WeatherData>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(WeatherData lhs, WeatherData rhs) {

            return lhs.degree.compareTo(rhs.degree);
        }
    });
```

and then apply it to your adapter.